# Putty pastes damaging indentation sometimes

Tags: linux, windows, putty, copy-paste

Often, when I am pasting from windows to putty, it breaks indentation.

Example below:

[image]

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

This looks like not a `vi/vim` effect, as it occurs in other editors too, and `set paste` or `set nopaste` does not help.

Comment: Could you perhaps have auto-indent active on your vim?

Answer (score 1):

If you *are* using vim, and you want auto-indent to be working most of the time, issue this command for the session where you want to paste.

```
:set paste
```

It won't do anything visible, but when you put it in insert mode it will paste things without trying to reformat it for you.  If you want to type new code in that same session and you do want the formatting help, use the command

```
:set nopaste
```